# How to determine the number of isomorphism types of groups of a given order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

if $G$ is a group whose order is $n$ can we determine the number of isomorphism types for this number or not ?

for instance, if $n=4$ we have 2 types, $Z_4$ and $Z_2 \times Z_2$ " Klein 4-group"

for any number n, is a similar calculation possible ?

in other words, let $P$ is a function from Natural numbers into natural numbers which for any number $n$ gives the number of possible structures for a group of order $n$

can we find a formula for this function in terms of $n$ and using operation like addition, multiplication, etc ?

Comment: No, it's not that easy. In fact, it can be extremely difficult. For **abelian** groups is easier and it is based on the name of partitions of the powers of the primes that divide $\,n\,$.

Comment: @DonAntonio , yup , it's easy for abelians groups using fundemental theorem for finite generated abelian groups or one of the other version of the theorem , but for nonabelian , is there  no approximate answer ? or limited answer " e.g under particular conditions " ?

Comment: to quote Aluffi's beautiful Algebra: Chapter 0 — To appreciate the difference in complexity, note that there are 42 abelian groups of order 1024 up to isomorphism... allegedly, there are 49,487,365,402 if we count noncommutative ones as well.

Comment: and then the footnote: This comparison is a little unfair, however, since it so happens that more than 99% of all groups of order < 2000 have order 1024.

Comment: I have written some related material in these answers: [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/241381/12952) [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/324921/12952)

Answer (score 4):

In view of all the information about how difficult and large $P(n)$ is, I should add the slightly consoling fact that it is algorithmically computable (and in fact primitive recursive).  The reason this is only *slightly* consoling is that I can't think of an algorithm significantly better than a brute force search through all the groups, nested with brute force searches for isomorphisms between them.

Comment: exactly, this very simple example shows just how far removed "computability" can be from feasibility

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice table on [OEISWiki](http://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_order_n#Table_of_number_of_distinct_groups_of_order_n) which shows the number of isomorphism classes for a group of order n - you should notice that they are quite sporadic. In particular, for groups of order $2^n$, the [number of isomorphic classes](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_2%5En) grows quite considerably, especially relative to groups of similar size.

Answer (score 3):

If you are seriously interested in this topic, you could look at the paper

Hans Ulrich Besche, Bettina Eick, and E.A. O'Brien.
A millennium project: constructing small groups.
Internat. J. Algebra Comput., 12:623-644, 2002,

which describes how the groups of order up to 2000 (which can be accessed in the GAP or Magma small groups library) were computed.

Comment: is this paper a book or what ?
edit: does this paper need a background from computational group theory ?