# Is it known whether all prime powers $p^k$ with $k\ge 8$ are group-abundant?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

Denote the number of groups of order $n$ by $gnu(n)$.

A natural number $n\ge 1$ is called group-abundant, if $gnu(n)>n$, group-perfect, if $gnu(n)=n$ and group-deficient, if $gnu(n)<n$.

I wonder, which prime powers $p^k$ ($p$ prime , $k\ge 1$) are group-abundant, group-perfect and group-deficient.

I could solve the case $k\le 7$ completely using the higman's PORC-functions.

The only group-abundant prime powers $p^k$ with $k\le 7$ are $2^5,2^6,2^7$ and $3^7$, all the other prime powers
are group-deficient (there are no group-perfect prime powers for $k\le 7$):

The numbers $2^8$ and $3^8$ are group-abundant as well as $2^9,2^{10}$ and $2^{11}$.

> Is it known whether all prime powers $p^k$ with $k\ge 8$ are group-abundant ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422120/known-bounds-for-the-number-of-groups-of-a-given-order) the number of groups of order $p^k$ satisfies
$$ gnu(p^k) \geq p^{\frac{2}{27}k^2(k-6)}.$$
Filling in $k \geq 8$ gives
$$ gnu(p^k) \geq p^{\frac{2}{27}k\cdot 8\cdot 2} > p^{k},$$
so all prime powers $p^k$ with $k \geq 8$ are group-abundant.

Comment: Thank you. A superb answer. I hoped that the lower limits would give a value $k$, for which it can be shown that $p^k$ is group-abundant, but I did not expect that it is already the case for $k=8$.