# Number of groups of order n as a series coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, finite-groups, generating-functions, groups-enumeration, analytic-combinatorics

Consider the sequence [A000001](http://oeis.org/A000001) in oesis.org:

$ g_{n}= $ number of (isomorphism classes of) groups of order n.

Is it known for which $ z $ the generating function $  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_{n}z^{n} $ converges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known (see [Known bounds for the number of groups of a given order.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422120/known-bounds-for-the-number-of-groups-of-a-given-order?rq=1)) that there is a constant $C$ such that for any $n$, $$g_n\leq n^{C(\log n)^2}.$$  It follows that $\limsup g_n^{1/n}\leq 1.$  On the other hand, clearly $g_n\geq 1$ for all $n\geq 1$, so $\limsup g_n^{1/n}\geq 1$.  Thus $\limsup g_n^{1/n}=1$, and so the radius of convergence of $\sum g_nz^n$ is $1$.