# Order of the smallest group containing subgroups isomorphic with all groups of order $n$

Tags: group-theory

Seems similar to [this question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324913/order-of-the-smallest-group-containing-all-groups-of-order-n-as-subgroups) but I want to calculate it for $n = 1\ldots6$. I know that for $n=1$ it is trivial as the only group of order 1 is the trivial subgroup of $\{e\}$, but which groups should I consider for larger $n$ and how do I know I have considered all possibilities?

Comment: Also $n=5,6$ are obvious.

Comment: Small groups are classified, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups I guess it's a manual work to figure out the smallest common supergroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=4$, it is easy to check that the correct group is
$$\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2\ ,$$
which has order $8$.

---

There are two groups of order $6$: the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and the symmetric group $S_6$. The biggest cyclic subgroup of $S_6$ is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (e.g. generated by $(123)$). It follows that the smallest group containing all the groups of order $6$ as subgroups cannot have order smaller than $12$. We take the group
$$G=S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2\ ,$$
then obviously $S_3$ is a subgroup, and we see $\mathbb{Z}_6$ as the subgroup generated by $((123),1)$. This group has order $12$.

---

The other cases are trivial.

Comment: Any why is $n=6$ trivial?

Comment: @freakish Because there is only one group of order $6$.

Comment: What? There are two: $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and the symmetric group $S_3$.

Comment: @freakish Damn, I feel stupid now! Sorry, it's been a while since my group theory class. I'll edit.

Comment: For $n=6$ the answer is the Dihedral group $\mbox{Dih}_6\simeq S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ which has 12 elements. But I only know this because I've read the classification of small groups (and their subgroups), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups#List_of_small_non-abelian_groups

Comment: @freakish I got to the same conclusion, see the updated answer.

Comment: Your answer is correct and I get why it is correct by looking at the table of groups, but how does one check all the groups? Which groups do you look at? For example, when I considered $n=2$ I thought of $Z_2$ and $Z_3^*$, and it took me a bit of work to show that they are isomorphic. So how do I know what groups of a given order are?

Comment: @Joald For small groups, you can build all the possible Cayley tables for the given order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table