# Cayley's Theorem and proving $S_n$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

If $G$ is a finite group, then $G$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $S_n$.

I was able to prove this theorem by using the fist part of Cayley's theorem.

But I can't prove that $S_n$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations. How can I show that?

Comment: $S_n$ is typically defined as the group of permutations on $n$ points. You'll need to state the definition you are working with if you want to prove that they're equivalent.

Comment: This is step 4 of Alexander Gruber's answer to the linked question, found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/369702/10513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is step 4 of Alexander Gruber's answer to the linked question, found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/369702/10513).