# Find permutation group from a group.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

For $G, H$
given below, I want to build corresponding permutation groups.
For $G, H$
given below, I want to build corresponding permutation groups.

$H: \langle\{2,4,8,10,14,16\}, \times_{18}\rangle$

$G: \langle \{3,6,9, 12,15,18\}, \times_{21}\rangle$

How do I achieve that?

Let the new groups be $G', H'$, but then what property is needed to find co-domain value for each element in them?

$G'$ : \begin{pmatrix}3&6&9&12 & 15& 18\\ 
&&&&&\end{pmatrix}

$H'$ : \begin{pmatrix}2&4&8&10& 14& 16\\ 
&&&&&\end{pmatrix}

This seems wrong, as $G', H'$ will be composed of some number of permutations.

If so, how many permutations are possible in either group $G', H'$?

$G: \langle \{3,6,9, 12,15,18\}, \times_{21}\rangle$

How do I achieve that?

Let the new groups be $G', H'$, but then what property is needed to find co-domain value for each element in them?

$G'$ : \begin{pmatrix}3&6&9&12 & 15& 18\\ 
&&&&&\end{pmatrix}

$H'$ : \begin{pmatrix}2&4&8&10& 14& 16\\ 
&&&&&\end{pmatrix}

This seems wrong, as $G', H'$ will be composed of some number of permutations.

If so, how many permutations are possible in either group $G', H'$?

Comment: This might be useful:$$a_{i} \rightleftharpoons P_{a_{i}}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{1} & a_{2} & \cdots & a_{n} \\
a_{i} \cdot a_{1} & a_{i} \cdot a_{2} & \cdots & a_{i} \cdot a_{n}
\end{array}\right)$$, where $a_i$ is an element of your  $H$, and $P_{a_i}$ is corresponding permutation element.

Comment: Hence $$a_{i} a_{j} \rightleftharpoons P_{a_{i} a_{j}}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{1} & a_{2} & \cdots & a_{n} \\
a_{i} \cdot a_{j} \cdot a_{1} & a_{i} \cdot a_{j} \cdot a_{2} & \cdots & a_{i} \cdot a_{j} \cdot a_{n}
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: @narip Thanks, but as was a small group. So, if could give solution too. Or, need construct an even smaller group?

Comment: @narip Thanks, but don't where to look for it. The problem was not based on any source. So, if any search keywords or explicit term were given, please.

Comment: [This](https://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/4033/absalg20.pdf) may be helpful. There's a concrete example inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the permutation group, see [this proof of Cayley's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/369702/104041).

For example, the element of the permutation group corresponding to $3$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 & 18\\
9 & 18 & 6 & 15 & 3 & 12
\end{pmatrix}.$$

This is because:

$$\begin{align}
3\times 3&=9,\\
3\times 6&=18,\\
3\times 9&\equiv 6\pmod{21},\\
3\times 12&\equiv 15\pmod{21},\\
3\times 15&\equiv 3\pmod{21},\\
3\times 18&\equiv 12\pmod{21}.
\end{align}$$

One can relable, so that the permutation corresponding to three is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
3 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks, corrected the typo. of putting in  $18$ in place of $3$ for $(3,6)$. Is it not just one permutation, or the group has this permutation (or some permutations of disjoint co-domains of elements) as the only one inside it? But, what will be the order of group then?

Comment: You're welcome, @jiten. If $K\cong L$, then $|K|=|L|$ for all groups $K, L$.

Comment: To restate the last comment: there should be five more distinct permutations, as order of group $=6$.

Comment: Yes, @jiten. I gave an example only. I recommend that you compute the rest yourself.

Comment: Relabel of the co-domain elements is  the key then to create rest. But, that way get # of distinct permutations $=6!$, while should get only $6$. So, what limits the number of permutations?

Comment: No, @jiten. The number of permutations in the permutation group is six. Each of its elements corresponds to exactly one element of the original group and *vice versa*. See the proof of Cayley's Theorem. Try to understand my example above. Also, instead of writing another comment in five minutes, give it some time; be patient.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that a different approach, combining existing answers, may help...

So consider your group that is multiplication modulo 18.  You can work with powers of 2:

$H: \langle\{2,4,8,16,14,10\}, \times_{18}\rangle$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}& 2&4& 8& 16&14& 10\\ \hline
 2&  4&  8& 16& 14& 10&  2\\
 4&  8& 16& 14& 10&  2&  4\\
 8& 16& 14& 10&  2&  4&  8\\
16& 14& 10&  2&  4&  8& 16\\
14& 10&  2&  4&  8& 16& 14\\
10&  2&  4&  8& 16& 14& 10\\
\end{array}

Note how the powers of $2$ increase as you go through the table to the right and down.

Then, according to @narip, each row can be thought of as a permutation...  For example, look at the heading and the top row in the table.  They are the permutation

$H'$ : \begin{pmatrix}
  2&  4&  8& 16& 14& 10\\ 
  4&  8& 16& 14& 10&  2
\end{pmatrix}

The next row in the table corresponds to another permutation:

$H''$ : \begin{pmatrix}
  2&  4&  8& 16& 14& 10\\ 
  8& 16& 14& 10&  2&  4
\end{pmatrix}

and so on...

The general form of the permutations is

$$H^a : \begin{pmatrix}
  2^1&  2^2&  2^3& 2^4& 2^5& 2^6\\ 
  2^{1+a} & 2^{2+a} & 2^{3+a} & 2^{4+a} & 2^{5+a} & 2^{6+a}
\end{pmatrix}(\bmod 18)$$

You can also take transposes of columns to arrive similarly at the result.